# best-result search using multiple tags on a column that stores values as CSV

Tags: php, mysql, sql, tags, sql-like

I have tags stored in a column that are separated by commas. I'm trying to create a best match search.

I do not want to match partial strings, so I've added a comma at the beginning and end of each string like so `,apple,orange,banana,` so that I can look up using `LIKE '%,apple,%` and it doesn't care what the position is.

how do I get the list of ids in order based on the *best match compared to the search tags*

is there a pure mySQL way of doing this?

Right now I'm dealing with it in PHP by looping through each tag and building out an array that counts the number of matches. 99% of time there will be a max of up to 5 tags being searched.

*also in my case I'm using two tag fields/columns that have separate tag categories*

Comment: You should include some sql SCHEMA, and a more detail sample with real data of what you have and what is your expect result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0d305/1)

Without a schema I imagine you need something like this.

```
SELECT 
    t.tagID, 
    t.tagText, 
    num_match.num_appear,
    ((LENGTH(`tagText`) - LENGTH(REPLACE(`tagText`, ',', '')))/LENGTH(',')) - 1 as wordnumber,
    (num_match.num_appear / (((LENGTH(`tagText`) - LENGTH(REPLACE(`tagText`, ',', '')))*1.0/LENGTH(',')) - 1)) *100 as porcentage

FROM 
    tblTAG t left join
    (SELECT tagID, count(tagID) as num_appear
     FROM
         (( SELECT tagID
            FROM  tblTAG
            WHERE tagText LIKE '%,apple,%'
         ) union all
         (  SELECT tagID
            FROM  tblTAG
            WHERE tagText LIKE '%,banana,%'
         )) as result
     GROUP BY tagID
    ) as num_match 
    ON t.tagID = num_match.tagID
```

Comment: Thanks @Juan, pretty close, I've played around a bit to get what I needed, the matching tags compared to the number of tags being searched
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8ce20/14

Comment: Hope that mean your problem is solve and consider accept my answer. Oherwise let me know if you need anything else. Just remember next time try to put a more complete example so be easy to understand whole problem.